# Can't find string.contains in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app, I want to see if my string contains certain characters but `IntelliSense` is not returning anyting for `string.Contains()`.

Has this method been deprecated or not made it into .NET Core 2.x? If so, how do I go about looking for certain characters in my string?

For example, my string is `x287v4d-127` and I'm trying to see if this string has a dash `-` in it.

Comment: It's there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-2.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_

Comment: Are you using the `System` namespace, or perhaps missed a reference?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to System.  You can either use string.Contains("-") or string.IndexOf('-').

Comment: My usage was wrong! I was trying to use it like this: `string.Contains(myString);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Contains on the object, not on the type.

So for example:

```
   string s1 = "x287v4d-127";
   bool b = s1.Contains("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` is a method of a string instance.  It's not a static method.

Try:

```
var mystring = "x287v4d-127";
if(mystring.Contains("-")
{
    //  Do whatever
}
```

You can also use `mystring.IndexOf("-",StringComparison.Ordinal)>-1`
The `StringComparison.Ordinal` makes it run as fast as the Contains.
'

Answer (score 0):

It is there in [`.Net Core 2.1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-2.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_) as well

You might have missed to add **`Using System;`** namespace,

Answer (score 0):

Ummm are you looking for a static method? You should be calling a method of an instance. Try:

```
"Hello World".Contains("Hello");
```